# Using an Objective-C++ class with C++ instance variables in Objective-C code

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c++

I'm writing an Objective-C++ class interface that has to be usable from both Objective-C and Objective-C++. The problem is that, because it must be usable from Objective-C, I cannot simply use a C++ type. I want to do it using pointers and I came up with this:

```
@interface SXDiff : NSObject {
@private
#ifdef __cplusplus
  dtl::Diff<std::string, std::vector<std::string> > *_diff;
#else
  void *_diff;
#endif
}

...

@end
```

Can any problems occur when doing this? Is there a better way of doing this?

---

Note that the use of pointers is just to get the size of the ivar to be the same in both Objective-C and Objective-C++. The ivar can only be used from within the class implementation of `SXDiff` (it's `@private`). The implementation is written in Objective-C++.

Comment: Just curious why do you want to use obj-c?

Comment: I have an application written in Objective-C and I want to use C++ code in just one of its classes.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? With LLVM 2.0+ you can declare your `dtl::Diff` in the implementation file using a class extension.

Comment: @Joe I am using Apple clang version 3.0, based on LLVM 3.0svn.

Comment: Why not avoid the #ifdef altogether and just use a void*. Another option would be to wrap the c++ class into a struct and use that for hiding (pimpl idiom). Since C knows structs and pointers to structs that should work, too.

Comment: Ya try moving the ivar declaration into a class extension in the `.mm` file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Apple LLVM version 2.0+ try moving all of your C++ code from the header into a class extension.

```
//SXDiff.h
@interface SXDiff : NSObject {
}

...

@end
```

```
//SXDiff.mm
#include "dtl/dtl.hpp"

@interface SXDiff()
{
    dtl::Diff<std::string, std::vector<std::string> > *_diff;
}
@end

@implementation SXDiff

...

@end
```

Comment: I didn't know this were possible, because GCC always gave me an error when trying that. clang doesn't. Thanks! This also eliminates the need for a pointer.

Comment: BTW, an interesting new feature in the latest SDK: You can now add ivars using a {} block after @implementation rather than using a class extension.